# How to check if a firebase branch exists in multiple levels

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below you will see an image of my Firebase database.

I am struggling to find a solution to my current problem.

I have a user who needs to see if they have all the tick boxes achieved. Any solution(s) is much appreciated.

I have a reference that reads a snapshot. Based on the snapshot I have these keys from that snapshot, I can then use them to fetch another set of keys that I use to see if the user has achieved this key or not. (Hope that makes sense).

I'm able to fetch the first part, but the deeper I go, my For/In loop keeps repeating itself and so all the text is colored green when I only want the ones (KPIs or targets) that the user has colored green and the ones he/she has not achieved is colored black.

[image: Firebase Database]

This image displays text where the student has one of the kpis and so it is green. When it is black, it means they have not achieved this. I want the method to read through all branches and see if his/her StudentUID is present and if so highlight the text green when the screen is loaded.

[image]

See the code below.

```
func checkStudentKpiAchievements(){
    
    StudentUID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "StudentUID") ?? "Nil"

    let myRef = Database.database().reference().child("KpisInThatLevel").child("Starfish")
    
        myRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot1 in
            
            let childSnaps = snapshot1.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                                
                for child in childSnaps {
                    
                    Database.database().reference().child("AttainedKpisFromStudents").child("Starfish").child(child.key).observe(.value, with: { snapshot2 in
                      
                        let yesAchieved = snapshot2.childSnapshot(forPath: self.StudentUID)
           
                        if (yesAchieved.hasChildren()) {
                            
                            print(true)
                            self.kpiDescription.textColor = UIColor.green

                            
                        } else {
                            
                            self.kpiDescription.textColor = UIColor.black

                        }
                     
                    })
                }
              
        })

}
```

Comment: "*my For/In loop keeps repeating itself*" - please edit the question to explain exactly what is happening that's different than what you expect.  We can't see your database, so we don't know what this code is going to do with that data we can't see.  There should be enough information in your question that anyone can use to reproduce the unexpected behavior as you describe it.  If you have logging output, please show that along with your log statements so we can follow along.

Comment: Why do you need to access UserDefaults to get the same load of data every time you call the checkStudentKpiAchievements function?

Comment: Agree with the above. Additionally, in programming, vars should never be capitalized - *StudentUID* - for example should be *studentUID*. Caps are reserved for Classes, Structs, Enums. Also, this is a little misleading *(forKey: "StudentUID") ?? "Nil"* because even if the key is not found, which would be nil, it's still a valid non-nil string value of `"Nil"` and that would lead to an issue here *forPath: self.StudentUID*. Better to let it be nil and test for nil so the code doesn't actually query for a path */Nil/*

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure the exact intent of the code flow so far as i am getting is that you want to pass the retrieved keys from one `snapshot1`  to pass them to next query as `snapshot2` .

so pleas try the following if that works for you

**solution block 1**

```
func checkStudentKpiAchievements() {
    StudentUID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "StudentUID") ?? "Nil"
    let myRef = Database.database().reference().child("KpisInThatLevel").child("Starfish")
    
    myRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot1 in
        let childSnaps = snapshot1.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        
        let dispatchGroupFlow1 = DispatchGroup()
        
        for child in childSnaps {
            dispatchGroupFlow1.enter()
            
            Database.database().reference().child("AttainedKpisFromStudents").child("Starfish").child(child.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot2 in
                let yesAchieved = snapshot2.childSnapshot(forPath: self.StudentUID)
                
                if (yesAchieved.hasChildren()) {
                    print(true)
                    self.kpiDescription.textColor = UIColor.green
                } else {
                    self.kpiDescription.textColor = UIColor.black
                }
                
                dispatchGroupFlow1.leave()
            })
        }
        
        dispatchGroupFlow1.notify(queue: .main) {
            //perform if any else is needed
        }
    })
```

the above block is written to pay attestation ot the asynchronous behavior.

although assuming if this is only one purpose of doing all these reads i am sure there could be better and more efficient way to perform this ,but for that you need to restructure your database .
if you have other functions that uses and turns out to be more efficient in the current structure then just stick with it .

EDIT:

```
  func checkStudentKpiAchievements() {
    StudentUID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "StudentUID") ?? "Nil"
    let myRef = Database.database().reference().child("KpisInThatLevel").child("Starfish")

    myRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot1 in
        let childSnaps = snapshot1.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]

        let dispatchGroupFlow1 = DispatchGroup()

        for child in childSnaps {
            dispatchGroupFlow1.enter()

            Database.database().reference().child("AttainedKpisFromStudents").child("Starfish").child(child.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot2 in
                let yesAchieved = snapshot2.childSnapshot(forPath: self.StudentUID)

                if (yesAchieved.exists()) {
                    print(true)
                    self.kpiDescription.textColor = UIColor.green
                } else if(!yesAchieved.exists()) {
                    print("in else if")
                    self.kpiDescription.textColor = UIColor.black
                }else{
                   print("in else ")
                        }

                dispatchGroupFlow1.leave()
            })
        }

    dispatchGroupFlow1.notify(queue: .main) {
        //perform if any else is needed
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Rainy, unfortunately, the above code still doesn't highlight the kpiDescription text color green when the student has this key. All the text turns up are black =(

Comment: check by replacing `yesAchieved.hasChildren()` with `yesAchieved.exists()` ?

Comment: please pay attestation to prints and let me know them

Comment: Hi, I checked the prints for the updated code and it comes up as true for the first value which is correct, however, it doesn't highlight the KPI green but black. It highlights the rest of the other KPIs black because the last value is black and like Doug mentioned above, maybe it's due to the code being a for/in loop which repeats itself so it will take the last value as false and loop round to all KPIs and highlight them all black.

Comment: Oh the prints say true, true, true, in else if. So all the KPI texts are black due to the last in else if clause.

Comment: so definitely that is the reason , is it as according to the data or you find it any unexpecting ?